# Create Email HTML Using Partial in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: email, zend-framework2, partial

I'm working on a system where we want to queue up a batch of emails and then send them using a queue (so I can't use \Zend\Mail directly).  The goal is to *not* have HTML inside the models that are creating the emails but instead have them in a view file.  I'm trying to call the partial view helper inside the models (which I did in ZF1) but can't find anything on the web on how to do this.  Is this possible in ZF2 or is there a better way?  I've managed it before where we've had the HTML inside the models and it's been a mess.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a template somewhere, pull the renderer from your service locator, and render away:

```
<?php
// this assumes you're in some AbstractActionController, 
// but you could be in some service class that has the 
// renderer injected, etc.

// template vars
$vars = array(/* .... */);

// create a ViewModel
$vm = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel($vars);

// path to your email template, compatible with your template map config. 
$tpl = 'mymodule/emails/some-email-template.phtml';
$vm->setTemplate($tpl);

// get the renderer from the ServiceManager, so it's all nicely configured.
$renderer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\View\Renderer\RendererInterface');

// render some HTML
$html = $renderer->render($vm);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

**1.** In the **module.config** define those HTML mail content template views.

```
'view_manager' => array( 
    (...)
    'template_map' => array(
        'mail_content_1' => __DIR__ . '/../view/<MODULE_NAME>/mail_content_1.phtml',
    ),
    (...)
)
```

**2.** Load the **Template View** in your model and get the HTML.

```
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

public function getMailHTML() {
    $view = new ViewModel;

    $variables = array( "parm1" => "value1" );      

    //SET THE VARIABLES, LIKE IN PARTIALS
    $view->setVariables( $variables );

    //SET THE TEMPLATE VIEW KEY DEFINED IN THE module.config
    $view->setTemplate( 'mail_content_1' );

    //YOU'LL HAVE TO BE ABLE TO USE THE ServiceManager IN YOUR MAIL MODELS.
    //RENDERING THE VIEW YOU'LL GET THE HTML
    return $this->serviceManager->get( 'viewrenderer' )->render( $view );
}
```